# Once only notification with DeliveryDelay with AWS SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, event-handling, amazon-sqs

In a web application, people upload files to be processed. File processing can take anywhere between 30 seconds and 30 minutes per file depending on the size of the file. Within an upload session, people upload anywhere between 1 and 20 files and these may be uploaded within multiple batches with the time lag between the batches being up to 5 minutes.

I want to notify the uploader when processing has completed, but also do not want to send a notification when the first batch has completed processing before another batch has been uploaded within the 2-5 minute time period. Ie. the uploader sees himself uploading multiple batches of files as one single "work period", which he may only do every couple of days.

Instead of implementing a regular check, I have implemented the notification with AWS SQS:
- on completion of each file being processed a message is sent to the queue with a 5 minute delivery delay.
- when this message is processed, it checks if there is any other file being processed still and if not, it sends the email notification

This approach leads to multiple emails being sent, if there are multiple files that complete processing in the last 5 minutes of all file processing.

As a way to fix this, I have thought to use an AQS SQS FIFO queue with the same Deduplicationid, however I understand I need to pass through the last message with the same Deduplicationid, not the first.

Is there a better way to solve this with event driven systems? Ideally I want to limit the amount of queues needed, as this system is very prototype driven and also not introduce another place to store state - I already have a relational database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to do this without using some sort of atomic central storage as suggested by @Ivan Shumov

In my case, a relational database is used to store file data and various processing metrics, so I have refined the process as:

- on completion of each file being processed a message is sent to the
  queue with a 5 minute delivery delay. The 5 minutes represents the largest time lag of uploads between multiple file batches in a single work session.
- when the first file is processed, a unique processing id is established, stored with the user account and linked to all files in this session
- when this message is processed, it checks if there is any other file being processed still and checks if there is a processing id against he user.
- if there is a processing id against the user, it clears the processing ids from the user and file records, then send

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS StepFunctions to control such types of workflows. 
1. Upload files to s3
2. Store jobs in DynamoDB 
3. Start StepFunction flow with job Id
4. Last step of flow is sending email notification
...
PROFIT!

Comment: How would I control multiple user interactions for file uploads with StepFunctions? Wouldn't that trigger multiple StepFunction invocations that I cannot coordinate either?

Comment: I mean multiple uploads of the same user

Comment: I assume that files uploading by client in one flow, for example: multiple file uploads or step-by-step uploading. You can controls that from frontend and launch job after all files uploaded successfully. And you can upload files directly to s3

Comment: Please, add details